# Why docker always hangs when trying to access container?

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

My idea is to install Jenkins and Docker in the same Dockerfile since I have to complete CI/CD workflows. So, for now, my Dockerfile is... (very simple Dockerfile but it is just for now)

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I'm facing a problem after building and running the container. I want to access the container by executing:

```
winpty docker attach CONTAINER_ID
```

But after executing this command, the console hangs and it's blocked.

Somebody know why is this happening? and the possible fix?

**EDIT:** 
After researching a little bit more, I've seen in the [dockerfile](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile) for jenkins/jenkins:lts that it has `ENTRYPOINT ["/sbin/tini", "--", "/usr/local/bin/jenkins.sh"]` command so that, when I try to access as I mentioned I only see this output, then the container does not redirect to bash. Is that correct? How can I go to bash?

Comment: Fixed by using: _docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash_

Comment: Add that on an answer, please.

Answer (score 3):

Fixed by using:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
```

If you use windows with winpty terminal:

```
winpty docker exec -it CONTAINER_ID bash
```